# How show all default languages in language list in android device?

Tags: android

I want to know that how to make available all supported languages in android device for that I can change entire device language in English(UK), English(US), Hindi etc. Right now only 5-6 languages are showing

I am able to download keyboard languages but I want to languages for entire device.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Locale.getAvailableLocales().`